# How do I pass a variable definition to a function?

Tags: c++, c

Im trying to pass firstFruit to function printFruit. But I'm receiving the error:expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token.

How could I also return fruitType if I was using a returnable function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct fruitType_struct {
   char name[51];
   char color[11];
   int fat;
   int sugar;
   int carbonhydrate;
} fruitType;

void printFruit(var fruitType){

      printf("Your fruit is...\nFruit: %s\nColor: %s\nFat: %d\nSugar: %d\nCarbonhydrate: %d\n\n", fruitType.name, fruitType.color, fruitType.fat, fruitType.sugar, fruitType.carbonhydrate);
}


int main(void) {

    fruitType firstFruit;
    fruitType yourFruit;

    strcpy(firstFruit.name, "Banana");
    strcpy(firstFruit.color, "Yellow");
    firstFruit.fat =  1;
    firstFruit.sugar = 15;
    firstFruit.carbonhydrate = 22;

    printFruit(firstFruit);
    }
```

Comment: `var fruitType` is not the C/C++ way. That's more JavaScript-like. You want something more like `fruitType myFruit`.

Comment: Note that this is partly because C/C++ are [statically typed langauges](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/22321/statically-typed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, in your print function, you are trying to use the `typedef` that you call `fruitType` as a variable name. That won't work.

---

The quick fix is:

```
void
printFruit(fruitType fruit)
{

    printf("Your fruit is...\nFruit: %s\nColor: %s\nFat: %d\nSugar: %d\nCarbonhydrate: %d\n\n",
    fruit.name, fruit.color, fruit.fat, fruit.sugar, fruit.carbonhydrate);
}
```

But this passes the `struct` by *value*. (i.e.) The entire contents of the `struct` must be pushed onto the stack.

---

It's more efficient to pass by pointer/reference (i.e.) only a pointer to the `struct` is pushed on the stack:

```
void
printFruit(const fruitType *fruit)
{

    printf("Your fruit is...\nFruit: %s\nColor: %s\nFat: %d\nSugar: %d\nCarbonhydrate: %d\n\n",
    fruit->name, fruit->color, fruit->fat, fruit->sugar, fruit->carbonhydrate);
}
```

To use this second form, call from `main` with: `printFruit(&firstFruit);`

---

To return a modified value, it's best to use a variation of the second form:

```
void
changeFruit(fruitType *fruit)
{

    strcpy(fruit->name,"Cherry");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To return fruit type from a func just return a variable of fruit type

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct fruitType_struct {
    char name[51];
    char color[11];
    int fat;
    int sugar;
    int carbonhydrate;
} fruitType;

void printFruit(fruitType fruit)
{
    printf("Your fruit is...\nFruit: %s\nColor: %s\nFat: %d\nSugar: %d\nCarbonhydrate: %d\n\n",fruit.name, fruit.color, fruit.fat, fruit.sugar, fruit.carbonhydrate);
}

fruitType getFruit(const char * a,const char * b , int c,int d,int e)
{
    fruitType firstFruit;

    strcpy(firstFruit.name, a);
    strcpy(firstFruit.color, b);
    firstFruit.fat =  c;
    firstFruit.sugar = d;
    firstFruit.carbonhydrate = e;

    return firstFruit;
}


int main(void) {

    fruitType firstFruit;
    fruitType yourFruit;

    strcpy(firstFruit.name, "Banana");
    strcpy(firstFruit.color, "Yellow");
    firstFruit.fat =  1;
    firstFruit.sugar = 15;
    firstFruit.carbonhydrate = 22;

    printFruit(firstFruit);

    yourFruit = getFruit("Jackfruit","Green",1,11,157);

    printFruit(yourFruit);

}
```

> Output :
>
> Your fruit is... Fruit: Banana Color: Yellow Fat: 1 Sugar: 15
>   Carbonhydrate: 22
>
> Your fruit is... Fruit: Jackfruit Color: Green Fat: 1 Sugar: 11
>   Carbonhydrate: 157